# SQL Server 2012 - Looking for duplicates with differences

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2012, I have a table like this:

```
Id  | AccountID  | Accession  | Status
----------------------------------------
1   | 1234567    | ABCD       | F
2   | 1234567    | ABCD       | F
3   | 2345678    | BCDE       | F
4   | 8765432    | BCDE       | F
5   | 3456789    | CDEF       | F
6   | 9876543    | CDEF       | A
```

I need to find rows that have the same Accession and a Status of "F", but a different `AccountID`.

I need a query that would return:

```
Id  | AccountID  | Accession  | Status
----------------------------------------
3   | 2345678    | BCDE       | F
4   | 8765432    | BCDE       | F
```

1 and 2 wouldn't be returned because they have the same `AccountID`. 5 and 6 wouldn't be returned because the status on 6 is "A" and not "F".

Comment: Perhaps a GROUP BY clause by Accenssion, by Status?

Comment: You are looking for multiple records with duplicated fields.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
;WITH NonDupAccountIDs AS
(
    SELECT AccountID,Accession, Status
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Status = 'F'
    GROUP BY AccountID,Accession, Status
    HAVING COUNT(Id) = 1
)
,DupAccessions AS
(
    SELECT Accession
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Status = 'F'
    GROUP BY Accession
    HAVING COUNT(AccountID) > 1
)
select a.AccountID, a.Accession, a.Status 
FROM NonDupAccountIDs a
INNER JOIN DupAccessions b
ON a.Accession = b.Accession
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative

```
Declare @Table table (id int,AccountID varchar(25),Accession varchar(25),Status varchar(25))
Insert into @Table (id  , AccountID  , Accession  , Status) values
(1, 1234567,'ABCD','F'),
(2, 1234567,'ABCD','F'),
(3, 2345678,'BCDE','F'),
(4, 8765432,'BCDE','F'),
(5, 3456789,'CDEF','F'),
(6, 9876543,'CDEF','A')

Select A.* 
 from  @Table A
 Join (
        Select Accession
         From @Table
         Where Status='F'
         Group By Accession
         Having Min(Accession)=Max(Accession)
            and count(Distinct AccountID)>1
      ) B on a.Accession=B.Accession
```

Returns

```
id  AccountID   Accession   Status
3   2345678     BCDE        F
4   8765432     BCDE        F
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as well.  If there are multiple sets of duplicates, this only returns one with the highest ID. [Example](http://rextester.com/ZNPE66198)

[John Cappelletti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1570000/john-cappelletti) had a great solution as well, his returns all duplicated values if there exists any incongruity. [Example](http://rextester.com/YRHR46430)

I had to add some more data to see what would happen.  You should decide how you will treat these occurrences.

```
select 
max(ID) ID,AccountID, Accession
from p where Status = 'F'
group by AccountID, Accession
having 
(select count(Accession) from (select max(ID) ID,AccountID, Accession from p where Status = 'F' group by AccountID, Accession) f where f.accession = p.accession)>1
;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT t2.Id, t1.AccountID, t1.Accession, t1.Status
FROM TABLE_NAME t2
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT AccountID, Accession, Status
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    GROUP BY Status, Accession, AccountID
) t1
ON t1.AccountID = t2.AccountID
```

Might need to play with this but should get you close. Remember to replace TABLE_NAME with your table.